# Ruby Script To Execute Shell Commands, But Doesn't Respect Ruby Version/Gem set

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

I have a ruby script that goes through and runs bundle update on all the folders in a directory. When I do this though, it uses the ruby version and gemset of the folder where the script is at. Essentially, what I want to do is be able to execute `sh scripts/update_gems.sh app_name` and have it use the gemset and ruby version of the that folder.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: How is the `ruby version of that folder` determined?

Comment: @arco444 it uses RVM to set the gemset and ruby version. Both are defined in the Gemfile or .ruby-version file.

Comment: Then I would think your script will need to read the file and parse out the required version before running an `rvm use {version}` each time a new directory is encountered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RVM struggled with this. Once I switched to Rbenv it worked like a charm.